# Override req express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to override `req` but it seems to not work

for example

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.hostname = req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] || req.hostname;
    req.test = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || req.protocol;
    req.protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || req.protocol;
    console.log(req.hostname);
    console.log(req.test);
    console.log(req.protocol);
    next();
})
```

If I have

x-forwarded-host = 'google.com'
x-forwarded-proto = 'https'

I will have

```
req.hostname = '127.0.0.1'
req.test = 'https'
req.protocol = 'http'
```

Comment: what you have should work. show some real code.

Comment: @KevinB done, I updated

Comment: Where is this middleware in relation to the route that is being processed? do the console logs happen?

Comment: Yes the console.log happen and I put the result I have in the bottom

Comment: seems as though `app.set('trust proxy', true)` would essentially do what you're trying to do with that middleware, no? https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table -> https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#trust.proxy.options.table